# How can I get my public wallet address for tax software?

Tags: ada, taxes, submission

ADA addresses that start in:

```
Ae2
DdzFF
addr1
```

are supported by accointing.com -> to submit tax reports.

The address I get (in Daedalus) is `acct_`

Can I turn the acct_ into one of the other formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess `acct_` is the address of your stake key, therefore belongs to the account ledger.

For payments, you would need to gather each of your payment addresses (these prefixes you shared) one by one.

If you tax software supports only payment addresses, it will omit rewards, which might or might not be a problem depending on your jurisdiction.

Comment: Ouch, this could be quiet a process. Is there some central mechanism to query this?

Comment: Check out blockfrost.io, it might help you if you do not want to run the node with the db-sync stack.